# Using this implementation as a starting point, please extend the polynomial addition function to allow polynomial coefficients (in another variable y)

Tags: java

i am stuck with this question:

> A[] = {5, 0, 10, 6}
>
> B[] = {1, 2, 4}
>
> The first input array represents `5 + 0x^1 + 10x^2 + 6x^3`
>
> The second array represents `1 + 2x^1 + 4x^2`
>
> And Output is `6 + 2x^1 + 14x^2 + 6x^3`

I have this code:

```java
class GFG {

    static int max(int m, int n) {
        return (m > n) ? m : n;
    }

    static int[] add(int A[], int B[], int m, int n) {
        int size = max(m, n);
        int sum[] = new int[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            sum[i] = A[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sum[i] += B[i];
        }

        return sum;
    }

    static void printPoly(int poly[], int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(poly[i]);
            if (i != 0) {
                System.out.print("x^" + i);
            }
            if (i != n - 1) {
                System.out.print(" + ");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int A[] = {5,0, 10, 6};

        int B[] = {1, 2, 4};
        int m = A.length;
        int n = B.length;
        System.out.println("First polynomial is");
        printPoly(A, m);
        System.out.println("\nSecond polynomial is");
        printPoly(B, n);
        int sum[] = add(A, B, m, n);
        int size = max(m, n);
        System.out.println("\nsum polynomial is");
        printPoly(sum, size);

    }
}
```

Q.1 Using this implementation as a starting point, please extend the polynomial addition function to allow polynomial coefficients (in another variable y)

For example

```
A[] = {5, 0, 10, {1,1}}
B[] = {1, 2, {0,1}}
```

now the input arrays represent respectively:

```
"5 + 0x^1 + 10x^2 + (1+y)x^3"
"1 + 2x^1 + (y)x^2"
And Output is "6 + 2x^1 + (10+y^1)x^2 + (1+y^1)x^3"
```

Hints
As can be readily seen, allowing polynomial coefficients (in another variable y), makes the problem recursive.

I have the following test cases:

```
    Test Case: 1
       Input:  A[] = [5, 0, 10, 6],   B[] = [1, 2, 4]
       Output: [6, 2, 14, 6]

   Test Case: 2
       Input:  A[] = [5, 0, 10, [1,1]],   B[] = [1, 2, [0, 1]]
       Output: [6, 2, [10, 1], [1, 1]]

   Test Case: 3
       Input:  A[] = [5, 0, [2, 1], [1,1, [4, 5, [55, 44]]]],   B[] = [1, 2, [0, 1]]
       Output: [6, 2, [2, 2], [1, 1, [4, 5, [55, 44]]]]

   Test Case: 4
       Input:  A[] = [5, 0, 10, [-1,1]],   B[] = [1, -2, [0, 1]]
       Output: [6, -2, [10, 1], [-1, 1]]

   Test Case: 5
       Input:  A[] = [4, 0, [0, -5], [-2,1]],   B[] = [1, 0, [0, 1]]
       Output: [5, 0, [0, -4], [-2, 1]]
```

I need help with this question..

Answer (score 0):

You have two arrays and you need to add corresponding elements.
Each array has only two kinds of elements as follows:

- a single `Integer` (which is a subclass of `Object`)
- an array of `Object`

If the corresponding elements are both single `Integer` then you just add them.

If the corresponding elements are both arrays then you first make both arrays the same size by adding zeros to the smaller array and then you add the corresponding elements of each array.

If one element is a single `Integer` and the corresponding element is an array, convert the single `Integer` to an array whose size equals the corresponding array and set all the elements of the converted array to zero (apart from the first element whose value is set to the single `Integer`)

Adding corresponding elements of the arrays is recursive since an element may be an array.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CFG {
    private static Object addElements(Object first, Object second) {
        boolean firstArray = first.getClass().isArray();
        boolean secondArray = second.getClass().isArray();
        if (!firstArray) {
            if (!secondArray) {
                return ((Integer) first).intValue() + ((Integer) second).intValue();
            }
            else {
                first = convertElement(first, (Object[]) second);
                return addElements(first, second);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (!secondArray) {
                second = convertElement(second, (Object[]) first);
                return addElements(first, second);
            }
            else {
                Object[] pair = sortElements((Object[]) first, (Object[]) second);
                pair[0] = adjustSmaller((Object[]) pair[1], (Object[]) pair[0]);
                int len = ((Object[]) pair[1]).length;
                Object[] result = new Object[len];
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    result[i] = addElements(((Object[]) pair[0])[i], ((Object[]) pair[1])[i]);
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    private static Object[] adjustSmaller(Object[] larger, Object[] smaller) {
        Object[] tmp = new Object[larger.length];
        System.arraycopy(smaller, 0, tmp, 0, smaller.length);
        Arrays.fill(tmp, smaller.length, tmp.length, 0);
        return tmp;
    }

    private static Object[] convertElement(Object source, Object[] array) {
        Object[] tmp = new Object[array.length];
        tmp[0] =source;
        Arrays.fill(tmp, 1, tmp.length, 0);
        return tmp;
    }

    private static Object[] sortElements(Object[] arr1, Object[] arr2) {
        Object[] sorted = new Object[2];
        int arr1len = arr1.length;
        int arr2len = arr2.length;
        if (arr1len > arr2len) {
            sorted[0] = arr2;
            sorted[1] = arr1;
        }
        else {
            sorted[0] = arr1;
            sorted[1] = arr2;
        }
        return sorted;
    }

    private static void test(Object[] a, Object[] b) {
        Object[] pair = sortElements(a, b);
        pair[0] = adjustSmaller((Object[]) pair[1], (Object[]) pair[0]);
        int len = ((Object[]) pair[1]).length;
        Object[] result = new Object[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            result[i] = addElements(((Object[]) pair[0])[i], ((Object[]) pair[1])[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test Case 1
        Object[] a = new Object[]{5, 0, 10, 6};
        Object[] b = new Object[]{1, 2, 4};
        test(a, b);
        // Test Case 2
        a = new Object[]{5, 0, 10, new Object[]{1, 1}};
        b = new Object[]{1, 2, new Object[]{0, 1}};
        test(a, b);
        // Test Case 3
        a = new Object[]{5, 0, new Object[]{2, 1}, new Object[]{1, 1, new Object[]{4, 5, new Object[]{55, 44}}}};
        b = new Object[]{1, 2, new Object[]{0, 1}};
        test(a, b);
        // Test Case 4
        a = new Object[]{5, 0, 10, new Object[]{-1,1}};
        b = new Object[]{1, -2, new Object[]{0, 1}};
        test(a, b);
        // Test Case 5
        a = new Object[]{4, 0, new Object[]{0, -5}, new Object[]{-2,1}};
        b = new Object[]{1, 0, new Object[]{0, 1}};
        test(a, b);
/*
Test Case: 1
    Input:  A[] = [5, 0, 10, 6]
            B[] = [1, 2, 4]
   Output:        [6, 2, 14, 6]
Test Case: 2
    Input:  A[] = [5, 0, 10, [1,1]]
            B[] = [1, 2, [0, 1]]
   Output:        [6, 2, [10, 1], [1, 1]]
Test Case: 3
    Input:  A[] = [5, 0, [2, 1], [1,1, [4, 5, [55, 44]]]]
            B[] = [1, 2, [0, 1]]
   Output:        [6, 2, [2, 2], [1, 1, [4, 5, [55, 44]]]]
Test Case: 4
    Input:  A[] = [5, 0, 10, [-1,1]]
            B[] = [1, -2, [0, 1]]
   Output:        [6, -2, [10, 1], [-1, 1]]
Test Case: 5
    Input:  A[] = [4, 0, [0, -5], [-2,1]]
            B[] = [1, 0, [0, 1]]
   Output:        [5, 0, [0, -4], [-2, 1]]
 */
    }
}
```

Running the above code produces the following output:

```
[6, 2, 14, 6]
[6, 2, [10, 1], [1, 1]]
[6, 2, [2, 2], [1, 1, [4, 5, [55, 44]]]]
[6, -2, [10, 1], [-1, 1]]
[5, 0, [0, -4], [-2, 1]]
```

As you can see, the output matches the expected output as indicated in your question.

Comment: How can i Implement a polynomial multiplication routine which similarly allows polynomial coefficients (in another variable y)? Considering a Test Case: 
       Input:  A[] = [5, [4, 6]],    B[] = [2, 4]
       Output: [10, [28, 12], [16, 24]]

Comment: @BhopeshSharma I don't understand your test case. Both `A` and `B` have two elements each. Why does the output contain three elements? In any case, you are basically asking another question, so simply post a new question (rather than asking another, separate question in a comment to my answer).